# Limit MXNet GPU Memory Usage

Tags: python, mxnet

**Is there a way that we can limit the Memory Allocation used by this Model to allow for Concurrent Models to Run?**

I'm currently using [InsightFace](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface) which is built on MXNet.

After loading the first model the GPU Mem stats reflect:

`utilization.gpu 74 utilization.memory 0 memory.free 13353 memory.used 2777 memory.total 16130`

After running the first inference through, it balloons, but the `GPU Utilization` is still very low at `3`:

`utilization.gpu 3 utilization.memory 0 memory.free 9789 memory.used 6341 memory.total 16130`

This makes me think that we should be able to load more models onto the same GPU, but unfortunately the memory is already allocated to MXNet.

---

**Solutions Tried:**

1. Trying `ctx.empty_cache()` between calls to the model - https://mxnet.apache.org/api/python/docs/api/mxnet/context/index.html#mxnet.context.Context.empty_cache
2. Trying `MXNET_GPU_MEM_POOL_RESERVE：60` -  https://discuss.mxnet.io/t/how-to-limit-gpu-memory-usage/6304/3
3. Using `gc.collect()` [Reset GPU memory using Keras 1.2.2 with MXnet backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47661254/reset-gpu-memory-using-keras-1-2-2-with-mxnet-backend/48939575#48939575)

But none of these worked.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [Environment Variables of MXNet](https://mxnet.apache.org/api/faq/env_var), it appears that the answer is no.

---

You can try setting `MXNET_MEMORY_OPT=1` and `MXNET_BACKWARD_DO_MIRROR=1`, which are documented in the "Memory Optimizations" section of the link I shared.

Also, make sure that `min(MXNET_EXEC_NUM_TEMP, MXNET_GPU_WORKER_NTHREADS) = 1` is true for you, which should be if you used the default values of this environment variables.